# Clicking beneath the overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a link that is clickable underneath an overlay. Can somebody please help me as i want the link to be unclickable when the overlay is being displayed.??.The implementation is in asp.Net mvc4

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, the CSS-command on the overlay could be: `pointer-events:none`.. maybe it will work in your case too..